# "Undefined references" using endnotes (both enotez and endnotes packages)

Tags: biblatex, endnotes

Please, consider this code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ kuhn:1982,
  author         = "Thomas Kuhn",
  title          = "La struttura delle rivoluzioni scientifiche",
  publisher      = "Einaudi",
  location       = "Torino",
  year           = "1978",
  edition    = "4",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
%\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{plain}{paragraph}{notes-sep=0pt}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\footcite[23]{kuhn:1982}
\printendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I compile with: pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex. However, I receive always the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                biblio
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

even if it seems to me that there is no problem in .pdf file. The same if I use `endnotes` package. Why this loop? Is there a way to solve or avoid it? Thanx

=========================================================================
Obviously, in my original code there is `\RequirePackage{filecontents}`. It's a mistake from copy/paste. I've TexLive 2014, update more the once every week. In any case:

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
 document
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  lipsum.sty    2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
  enotez.sty    2014/02/04 v0.7c Endnotes for LaTeX2e
   expl3.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 programming layer 
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3unicode-data.def    2014/11/23 v5465 L3 Unicode data
l3pdfmode.def    2014/11/23 v5466 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
xtemplate.sty    2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
  xpatch.sty    2012/10/02 v0.3 Extending etoolbox patching commands
scrlfile.sty    2014/10/28 v3.14 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
translations.sty    2014/01/23 v1.2a internationalization of LaTeX2e packages (
CN)
cnltx-base.sty    2014/01/05 v0.10 LaTeX tools and documenting facilities (CN)
 pgfopts.sty    2014/07/10 v2.1a LaTeX package options with pgfkeys
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
biblatex.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
 english.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
supp-pdf.mkii
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl    (english translation file `transl
ations-basic-dictionary')
references.bbl
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `filecontents` package (why would it?). There is something strange happening in the way biblatex and endnotez are working together.

Comment: Yes, infact I had that problem in a big .tex file with a separated .bib file. The trouble is the some one both with `enotez` and `endnotes`. I realize that is not so easy to identify this "strange" buhaviour

Answer (score 1):

In your MWE is a relevant command missing: `\RequirePackage{filecontents}`.

If I compile the following, a little bit changed MWE, I have no errors.  Please check this on your own computer.  If you still ahve problems please add `\listfiles` as first line of the MWE and recompile. Then check the list of used packages and versions and add it to your question. (I guess then your system is a little bit outdated ...)

Changed MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{kuhn:1982,
  author         = "Thomas Kuhn",
  title          = "La struttura delle rivoluzioni scientifiche",
  publisher      = "Einaudi",
  location       = "Torino",
  year           = "1978",
  edition    = "4",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}  % to create dummy text
\usepackage{enotez}
%\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{plain}{paragraph}{notes-sep=0pt}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\footcite[23]{kuhn:1982}

\blindtext[5]
\printendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` is irrelevant. For some reason, using `lipsum` instead of `blindtext` continues to cause the warning.